# device not ready firmware missing

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

Machine: HP dv9925nr, stock hardware.
OS: ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Issue: Broadcom wireless card seems to be missing firmware, according to error code from Networking menu: device not ready (firmware missing).

More info: I'm a truck driver, on the road, no ethernet connection available. If there is a driver or firmware file that I can download online, I can download with my tablet and transfer the file(s) to my laptop via sdcard.

Stumbling around:
Alright, with no replies, I stumbled around in the forum for several hours and came up with this:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx, which pointed me in the right direction. 
As it turns out, The Chip ID is BCM4322
The PCI-ID is [14e4:432b].
I then went to this page:http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43, which tells me that my wl card is partially supported.

Following the directions here: , I was able to download the file packages I needed, fwcutter, and the firmware b-43. I moved those files to the home directory on my dv9925nr, and opened the fwcutter package in Ubuntu software center. A page came up showing the file information, but the install button is greyed out and unclickable.
I also followed the directions here: , to UN black list my card and the software.

So now I believe I'm supposed to install fwcutter, then use the terminal to install the firmware which is stored locally.
Is that the right track?

**RESOLVED**
I managed to resolve this issue connecting an ethernet cable and letting the OS figure it out.

Comment: Please type `lspci -nn | grep 0280` in the terminal and add the output to the question.

Comment: Directions link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20No%20Internet%20access

Comment: Unblacklist link: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx

Comment: Yes, you should install fwcutter and then the firmware. The install button being greyed out is a bug fixed in 13.10 - the `dpkg -i` in the offline instructions is the method to install it from the terminal. You should only need to follow the offline section and not the switching (blacklisting) section. You can connect your tablet to the machine and turn on tethering (on the phone) to use it as an internet source to follow the online instructions which is easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy and paste all commands for accuracy one line at a time. Download this file [b43.zip](http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=231686&d=1361390484) to a flash drive then drag and drop the file to your ubuntu desktop. Right-click it and select Extract Here. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43

sudo cp Desktop/b43/* /lib/firmware/b43

sudo rmmod -f b43

sudo rmmod -f ssb

sudo modprobe b43
```

if you get errors continue with the rest of the commands, if you have not installed any other wireless driver your wireless should now be working.

These directions are for installing the driver without internet connection if you have working internet then just download the file to your desktop and follow the directions above.

I believe you will have to create an account at ubuntu forums and login to be able to download this driver.

Comment: This worked like a charm. +1