# Opening terminal leads to no edid issue

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics

SO here's the latest in my Ubuntu saga:
I've got an HP DV9925NR running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. After getting the [wireless issue fixed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367100/device-not-ready-firmware-missing), I let the OS update my drivers, including an Nvidia driver.
After the install, I rebooted, and I got boot into a blank screen. Several hours of chasing my tail in the forums here introduced me to GRUB, and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver).
Question 1: When I edit something in GRUB, how do I save it? I edited the "quick splash" to "nomodeset" five times and every time I went back to that screen, it was back to "quick splash".
Moving on, as I tinkered with the machine and none of the options worked, I tried logging into the guest account. It WORKED!!! (hey, I was amazed). I switched user to my account, and got the same login-loop (Enter PW, see the screen flicker, go black, then back to login screen) and switched back to guest. I deleted my account, added a new account with the same name and Admin privileges, and i've been setting up that new account.
Now when I open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1) (Q3) I get a running error that says, "No edid for VGA-1". I've searched all over this forum, but I haven't found anything that would point me to a solution. 
Question 2: What is "no edid for VGA-1" and how do I fix it?

Question 3: Is there a difference between terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and tty1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1)?

For now, i'll leave things as they are, and we'll see if I can keep this machine running long enough to accomplish something.

Comment: Question 1. In a terminal, type: sudo -i Then type: nano /etc/default/grub Edit your grub file and save. Then type: update-grub. To exit root, type: exit.

Comment: To save something you changed with the nano editor, type: CTRL-o Then exit with: CTRL-x(if you didn't change the default keybindings of nano).

Answer (score 0):

1. when saving (you did edit it with root privileges I assume)  and leaving /etc/default/grub do the following command:
   `sudo update-grub`
2. EDID is the information your monitor sends to your videocard. It consists of mainly maximum resolution and refreshrate. Not all monitors send this info, especially old ones. So if the absence of EDID left you stuck in a much lower resolution than your monitor is capable of, then it is time to reach for the manual override :-)
3. Yes, Ctrl-Alt-F1 is a virtual termina a.k.a console. It runs on the bare OS even before the X-window system starts. Ctrl-Alt-T is a program running on the X-window system and is called a terminal emulator. The most important difference is that the virtual terminals will still be there if the Xwindow system kicks the bucket or is screwed up beyond working state :-)

Comment: Well there's progress! The monitor in question is the screen attached to my HP DV9925 laptop. From what I could gather, the issue had to do with installing the latest suggested driver.

Comment: In reference to editing the GRUB file, I was following directions that had me editing the GRUB file in a GUI, using the GRUB console (press+hold shift right after BIOS screen).